# Can I save a file directly as an email attachment?

Tags: email, attachments

I often work on a file (e.g. an Excel sheet) and, when finished, want to mail it to someone. I find it a bit cumbersome to save it to the desktop and then attach it to a mailing (my desktop is a bit cluttered, I have to scroll through a lot of stuff before I find it in the selector), and I was wondering whether there isn't a way to save it into the attachment slot of a mail document directly?

Comment: Start here: [Mail from Excel with Outlook (Windows)](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/mail.htm)

Answer (score 0):

For Excel 2010 this can be done the following way: 
In the Excel menu go to "File" -> "Share". There you'll find the option to send the file as an email attachment.

I myself use a specific folder where I save all file I want to send out. It's on the very top of the root directory so it's easy to access through the Save-dialogue as well as the attachment dialogue of my email application.